# PHPbrew connection timeout

Tags: php, curl

CURL is not working with phpbrew, if I install a php version or php extension or something that use curl, the script doesn't finish.

Any ideas?

```
phpbrew ext install xdebug                                
Warning: Some extension won't be able to be built with php7. If the extension
supports php7 in another branch or new major version, you will need to specify
the branch name or version name explicitly.

For example, to install memcached extension for php7, use:

    phpbrew ext install github:php-memcached-dev/php-memcached php7 -- --disable-memcached-sasl

CurlKit\CurlException: (28) Resolving timed out after 10524 milliseconds
Trace:

    0) CurlKit\CurlDownloader->request('https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/xdebug/stable.txt')
    1) PhpBrew\Extension\Provider\PeclProvider->getPackageXml('xdebug', 'stable')
    2) PhpBrew\Extension\Provider\PeclProvider->buildPackageDownloadUrl('stable')
    3) PhpBrew\Extension\ExtensionDownloader->download(PhpBrew\Extension\Provider\PeclProvider, 'stable')
    4) PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand->execute('xdebug')
    5) call_user_func_array([PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand, 'execute'], ['xdebug'])
    6) CLIFramework\CommandBase->executeWrapper(['xdebug'])
    7) CLIFramework\Application->run(['/usr/local/bin/phpbrew', 'ext', 'install', 'xdebug'])
    8) PhpBrew\Console->runWithTry(['/usr/local/bin/phpbrew', 'ext', 'install', 'xdebug'])
    9) require('phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/scripts/phpbrew-emb.php')
```

Comment: It'sa  network problem, not PHP/cURL. It looks to me like a DNS issue.

Comment: I'm surfing on the net properly. I've always had several problems with Curl dns resolutions. I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS (no especial network configurations)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, agree with comments related to Network problem, but also, please look at article with some tricks - https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/PHP7